# Java Concurrency wake up thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, sleep

I have an assignment in concurrent programming, and I am wondering how I can go about something.
I have to have an elevator simulator, where people call elevators, elevators will collect them and bring them to their destination floor. When an elevator isn't doing anything it sleeps and the Person will have a method to wake the elevator(by pressing the button).

Eventually the program will have to run forever, with elevators being created at the start of it, and people being created at random times, constantly calling the elevator.
I'm wondering, how can I make it so the program runs forever, until I stop it, where the elevator waits for a Person to wake it.

In my main class I have this right now:

```
    new Thread(elevators[0]).start();

    panels[3].pressButton().getButtonPanel().pressButton(5);
    panels[1].pressButton().getButtonPanel().pressButton(0);
    panels[2].pressButton().getButtonPanel().pressButton(4);
```

I also have an array of People, but I want that to be something generated constantly and randomly.
So in the Person class they will wake the elevator, but how can I make the elevator sleep forever here?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run forever, just put all of your code inside a `while(true)` loop. To stop it, you can use break under right conditions. Alternatively (and to have a possibly cleaner code) use a `while(condition)` loop, where your condition gets changed from true to false by some method you can call. For example have all this in your class:

```
boolean shouldBeRunning = true;

(...)

while(shouldBeRunning){
    //all the logic here
}

(...)

public void stop(){
    this.shouldBeRunning = false;
}
```

To have elewator waiting until somebody calls it, use method `wait()`. A waiting thread can be 'woken up' if another thread calls `notify` on waiters monitor. Get some more info about `wait()` and `notify` to get a better understanding of it. Afterwards implementation should not be a problem then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I knew I can use wait(true) to run forever, it was mainly the implementation of continuously generating new people I wasn't really sure of. If i'm creating the threads in my main method, can I wake an elevator thread up inside of the Person class?

Comment: Well, actually you can only call notify only from a thread that owns the lock. But how about spawning elewator thread inside main class?

Comment: The elevator thread is started and run in the main thread. Where do I go from there?

Comment: There was a question on strictly wait-notify usage here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17419385/how-does-wait-and-notify-work

Comment: Thanks for the link. Any ideas on how I should continiously create a Person to use the elevator

Comment: If I get your target well, you could use a timer which would run some timerTasks at random times. Your task could be to create a Person and notify the elevator. (You'd need to read a bit about timer and timerTask to do this).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43634/discussion-between-byakuya-and-andyohart)

Comment: @Byakura that would be good, only noticed it now I'm in thanks